# What is the difference between thermal and electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, thermal-radiation

In my understanding thermal radiation and electromagnetic radiation is same, for example suppose we heat up a knife to high temperature then it glows red. This means the thermal radiation / electromagnetic radiation is red coloured light , however [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/623673/236734) it was noted in the comments that thermal radiation and electromagnetic radiation are not always the same. Examples of bio luminescence and lasers were given.

However, now I do not understand the fundamental difference between them. If thermal radiation is basically just photons, then what is electromagnetic radiation consisting of?

[Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61958/what-is-the-difference-between-radiation-and-electromagnetic-radiation)

Comment: maybe you should start with the history https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#History_of_discovery

Answer (score 5):

It goes like this: all thermal radiation is electromagnetic radiation, but not all electromagnetic radiation is thermal radiation. In that sense *electromagnetic* is the *type* of radiation, *thermal* is the *cause* of the radiation. There are, of course, other sources of electromagnetic radiation, besides thermal. Compare an incandescent light bulb (thermal radiation) to an LED (recombination radiation).